# Adding or subtracting values based on another field's contents

Tags: mysql, sql, case, aggregate-functions

I have a table with transactions. All transactions are stored as positive numbers, if its a deposit or withdrawl only the action changes. How do i write a query that can sum up the numbers based on the action

-actions-
1 Buy   2 Sell    5 Dividend

```
ID  ACTION     SYMBOL     PRICE    SHARES
1    1         AGNC       27.50    150
2    2         AGNC       30.00     50
3    5         AGNC        1.25    100
```

So the query should show AGNC has a total of 100 shares.

```
SELECT
   symbol,sum(shares) AS shares,
   ROUND(abs(sum((price * shares))),2) AS cost,
FROM bf_transactions
WHERE (action_id <> 5) 
GROUP BY symbol 
HAVING sum(shares) > 0
```

I was originally using that query when i had positive/negative numbers and that worked great.. but i dont know how to do it now with just positive numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This ought to do it:

```
SELECT symbol, sum(case action
    when 1 then shares
    when 2 then -shares
    end) as shares
FROM bf_transactions 
GROUP BY symbol
```

<kbd>[**SQL Fiddle here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/802f5/3)</kbd>

It is however good practice to [denormalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) this kind of data - what you appear to have now is a *correctly* normalized database with no duplicate data, but it's rather impractical to use as you can see in cases like this. You should keep a separate table with current stock portfolio that you update when a transaction is executed.

Also, including a `HAVING`-clause to 'hide' corrupted data (someone has sold more than they have purchased) seems rather bad practice to me - when a situation like that is detected you should definitely throw some kind of error, or an internal alert.

Comment: +1 for the very nice use of markdown for the fiddle link (and because you're correct :) )

Comment: Hehe saw someone else do it that way today - looked up the markdown  right away because it's nicer and cleaner than a real link methinks  :)

Comment: I've only ever used it for actual *keys*, but that looks awesome :)